# Angular Redux-Form Initialization Error: TypeError: Cannot read property of null

Tags: angular, redux, redux-form, angular-forms, angular-redux

I have an Angular 5.2.8 app with angular-redux/form 6.5.0 in it and I am getting this error when my form initializes.

```
    core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of null
    at Function.State.traverse (state.js:26)
    at Function.State.get (state.js:44)
    at eval (connect-base.js:92)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ReactiveConnect.ConnectBase.resetState (connect-base.js:90)
    at eval (connect-base.js:43)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4749)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at Function.State.traverse (state.js:26)
    at Function.State.get (state.js:44)
    at eval (connect-base.js:92)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ReactiveConnect.ConnectBase.resetState (connect-base.js:90)
    at eval (connect-base.js:43)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4749)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at eval (zone.js:861)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1517)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1543)
```

In my component I have imported the following:

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

I initialize my form like so:

```
 this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
      lastName: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
      email: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.pattern(this.emailRegex)]],
      email2: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.pattern(this.emailRegex)]],
      password: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.pattern('((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,50})'), Validators.minLength(6)]],
      phone: ['', [<any>Validators.pattern('^[0-9-]{1,20}'), Validators.minLength(10)]],
      company: ['', []],
      industry: ['', [Validators.required]],
      month: ['', []],
      day: ['', []],
      year: ['', []]
    }, {validator: this.matchingEmails('email', 'email2')});
```

And I have made sure that the reducers are combining properly. In fact this form works as expected on a different development environment. I have tried changing the version of angular-redux/form to 6.6.0 and 6.7.0 because it worked for this developer (https://github.com/angular-redux/form/issues/53) but did not for me. Any help would be super appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Still looking for a solution. Unfortunately nothing has worked so far. You have any luck?

Comment: I did not, but I can show you what I'm doing instead.